# Unable to apt update but can ping ubuntu.com/archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: apt, server, 20.04, updates, update-manager

Can anyone help me with this issue.

I was working on ubuntu vm which was fine, I'm able to install any package and update/upgrade the os until recently when I tried to install a package and update using `sudo apt update`, but the output says

```
0% [connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.81)]
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
  cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.83). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
  cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::103). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
  cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::101). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
  cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.83). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
  cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::103). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
  cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80
```

I'm able to ping all ip addresses and the archive.ubuntu.com successfully.

[dig archive.ubuntu.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSBQO.png)

The archives on the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file  are all set to `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu.`

I tried changing the nameserver to `8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4` on the `/etc/resolve.conf` file but to no avail.

I don't use proxy server and I did have stable network connection.
I can ping all the archives IP successfully.

How can I get this to work again please.